# Passing data between two fragments using a callback

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to pass data from one fragment to another using a callback but im having trouble doing it. In my activity I call a fragment `A`, that calls fragment `B`. In fragment `B` i select a item and I need to pass that item to fragment `A`. Can someone tell me how can I do that?

I know that with a callback I can get the data from fragment `B` to the activity, but how can I send that data to fragment `A` with keeping the state of that fragment?

Comment: You could add a listener, or a broadcast receiver.

Comment: @zgc7009 can you givem e an example?

Comment: Store it in SharedPreferences, so it's accessible anywhere -- then no listeners/receivers are needed.  And/or use the Otto library, which provides Android with a much needed notification Bus.

Comment: @Alchete has a good recommendation as well IF fragment A is not dependent on the change in fragment B, that is if something in Fragment A isn't supposed to happen when the value is changed/selected in fragment B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity should implement the callback, the callback can then find fragment B and post data to one of its public methods. If you make the public method in fragment B accept whatever data you need, you should be able to pass it straight through.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCallback(String data) {
    FragmentB frag = (FragmentB) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentB.class.getSimpleName());
    if (frag != null) {
        frag.myMethod(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the `Activity` as your "traffic controller": have `Fragment` A callback the `Activity` then have the `Activity` call into `Fragment` B.  Keep the fragments separated so they don't know of each other.

Comment: I like this idea as well if the fragments are only used in a single Activity and you don't end up creating redundant codes managing the same fragments in different activities.